Change width of output box in Jupyter Notebook
I was wondering if it is possibile to change the width of a Jupyter Notebook output box.

Here is my example code:
import pandas as pd

# Maak een DataFrame met je gegevens
data = {
    'eigen_of_inhuur': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    'Basis': ['Inzet vrachtauto', 'horizontaa/verticaal transport', 'horizontaal/verticaal transport',
                        'horizontaal/verticaal transport op perron', 'huur trilplaat, 5,0 ton, voor- en achteruit',
                        'huur wacker stamper', 'huur hydraulische sloophamer 2-4 ton, huur per...',
                        'huur mini- kraan 1.5 ton', 'huur mini- kraan 3.5 ton', 'huur mobiele kraan 14 ton',
                        'huur rups kraan 80 ton, Sennebogen', 'huur shovel 15 ton. 3000 ltr.',
                        'huur trilwals 7-9 ton, inkl. machinist, brandstof', 'inzet shovel', 'veeg/zuigauto klein Ravo'],
    'hoeveelheid': [47.45, 1, 96, 304.65, 315.04, 226.48, 11.2, 265.74, 420.81, 654.71, 56, 33.82, 2.88, 286, 1.34],
    'eenheid': ['uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur', 'uur']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Stel de maximale weergavebreedte van kolommen in
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

# Print de DataFrame
print(df)

How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance
I tried widening the box by html and css code and working in jupyterlab however this all seemed not to work (These were solutions presented in THIS question).

Does this answer your question? Increase width of Jupyter notebook output cell

If you are using Jupyter, you have a much more feature-rich way to view dataframes. Where your code says # Print de DataFrame change that to # Display de DataFrame. And where it says print(df) you can change that to simply df if that is the last line in the cell. By default the last line is special and gets evaluated and the type of data displayed in the corresponding feature-rich handling of Jupyter. If that line to invoke showing the dataframe isn't the last line, you can use display(df). ...

 You may was well use Python or IPython if you aren't going to take advantage of the features and then you can control the output width as you want because it is going to be only text anyway. More pertinent to your question here is why aren't you including in your post the actual version of the Jupyter software you are using. You vaguely write "I tried widening the box by html and css code and working in jupyterlab however this all seemed not to work" with no evidence demonstrating you actually did these things correctly. Plus, ...

 the question your reference has several answers detailing that they are version specific solutions. For example the JupyterLab early tech and Jupyter Notebook 6.4 and earlier and Jupyter NbClassic all use different things than JupyterLab versions 4+ (plus high versions 3) and Jupyter Notebook version 7+.

See 'How do I increase the cell width of the Jupyter version 7' here for controlling the cell width in current Jupyter Notebook 7+.
